# angular material icon not shown even after adding the link to index.html

Tags: angular

I have added the following link to my index:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

but still i dont see the icon on my page:

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</mat-icon>
```

in my app.module:

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

is there anything else should be added?

Comment: @huanfeng yes i have added

Comment: Could you paste your app.module.ts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the MatIconModule in your app?

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Comment: i restarted my engine and works and im going to accept your answer, by adding this in my app.module it did not work in the beginning but once I restarted the icon showed up,thanks